# IBM MQ 8 to 9 Migration

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, ibm-mq

We have Sprintboot application on Azure Linux VM which is connecting to IBM MQ 8 and connection goes via KPN.

Recently we have upgraded IBM MQ from 8 to 9. No settings are changed on application, but with IBM MQ 9 - we can see that post 30 mins - connections are getting timed out and new connections are getting created post every 30 mins.

Checked with IBM MQ 9 team - no timeout setting at their end.

Error -

```
[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.3.0.jar!/:9.2.3.0 - p923-L210708]
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host 'Host Details'. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLException[Connection timed out (Read failed)],3=,4=TCP,5=InputStream.read]

    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    enter code here`Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
```

Comment: Have to tried 9.2.4 or 9.2.0.4 to see if you still have the same issue?

Comment: Firewall timing out connections?

Comment: @Nic3500 - On Firewall we can see Session End Reason as - Age-out exactly after 30 mins since connection is created. Firewall is just allow or deny so not sure from which end Timeout is -Source or destination. There is no timeout settings on Firewall.

Comment: @Nic3500 - agree this sounds like firewall to me too

Comment: What is your channels HBINT set to?

Comment: @JoshMc - It is 0

Comment: Zero means there won't be any traffic if the channel has no messages. It also means that MQ needs to rely on keepalive to determine if the connection was broken.   You should set it to 15 or 30 seconds.   This will help both keep the firewall from timing out the session and allow MQ to catch a connection issue in less than 60 seconds.

Comment: @JoshMc - But we have kept it zero only earlier and it was not giving any issues. Like with MQ 8 and also in lower env - it is working fine with zero value with MQ 9.

Comment: Can you confirm what specific mq version you are running?   There are 3 major releases of "9" each with fix packs.   9.0 (out of support), 9.1, and 9.2.  Can you confirm the server or the client jars were updated or both?

Comment: Maybe there was a bug at an earlier release causing extra traffic which was keeping your connection active.  Maybe the firewall team made a change around the same time you upgraded.   Maybe the app traffic pattern has changed.  As a MQ admin with many years of experience I can tell you that you should set it higher than zero(disabled) because with out it mq can only rely on tcp keepalive to determine and will take longer to know about a connection problem.  In your case it should also keep your firewall from timing the connection out.

Comment: @JoshMc - MQ version is 9.1.0.7 and client jar version is - 9.2.3.0

Comment: I would suggest you try setting the HBINT. I think you will find this solves the problem.

Comment: @JoshMc - There two settings - Disconnect Interval and Heartbeat interval - We tried setting both values as 6000 and 300 sec respectively on MQ9. We were still able to see the Timeouts and Connection Broken errors only thing changed was the frequency which was earlier at 30 mins fixed time, post above change, it become random.

As soon as we switch to MQ 8 on same day - where both values are zero - we do not see the Timeouts.

Comment: What specific version of 8 and what was switched, the queue manager or the client jar files?  What did the TCP stanza of the qm.ini look like at v9.1 and now?

Comment: @JoshMc - Earlier version was Version: 8.0.0.16
Level: p800-016-210212

TCP Stanza - It is same as below for both 8.0 and 9.1

KeepAlive=Yes
SndBuffSize=0
RcvBuffSize=0
RcvSndBuffSize=0
RcvRcvBuffSize=0
ClntSndBuffSize=0
ClntRcvBuffSize=0
SvrSndBuffSize=0
SvrRcvBuffSize=0

Comment: @JoshMc - Client jar version is same for both - 9.2.3.0

Comment: What is the SVRCONN's SHARECNV set to?

Comment: @JoshMc - It is 10

Comment: 8.0 is out of support.   My only thought is that 8.0 is sending heart beat even though it shouldn't be with `HBINT(0)`.  I suggest trying the upgrade to 9.1.0 7 along with setting the `HBINT` down to 30 seconds or less and seeing how it goes.   If it does not resolve it,  you could take  a queue manager trace of the failure and of the 8.0 behavior and open a case with IBM.